# примечание не в цитате

Tags: частица-не, предлоги

Верховный суд отклонил жалобу Варвары Карауловой, осужденной за попытку примкнуть к боевикам из «Исламского государства» (террористическая организация, запрещенная в России. — Ред.).

Примечания автора, редакции пишутся в скобках для пояснения слов в цитате. Здесь же не цитата, а предложение в статье (новости), автор не указан. Тогда, может быть, достаточно написать в скобках так: (террористическая организация, запрещенная в России)?

Answer (score 2):

А кто сказал, что только в цитате? Здесь вот автор новостной статьи не разъяснил читателю, что это такое, а редактор счёл, что не все знают, что нужно пояснить, поэтому и внёс внутритекстовое примечание от своего имени. Примечания ведь могут принадлежать 1) автору, 2) редактору, 3) переводчику, 4) издателю, 5) специально приглашенному изд-вом лицу — тогда указывают, кому принадлежит.

http://www.az-print.com/index.shtml?FAQ&HelpBook/h027

Comment: Должно ли это примечание, написанное в скобках с маленькой буквы (т.е. не отдельным предложением), согласоваться по падежу с поясняемым словом? ---- ...из «Исламского государства» (террористической организации, запрещенной в России. — Ред.).

Comment: Нет, примечание входит в предложение на правах вставной конструкции (это террористическая организация...). Согласовывалось бы, если б было пояснение автора, оформленное как приложение:Верховный суд отклонил жалобу Варвары Карауловой, осужденной за попытку примкнуть к боевикам из «Исламского государства» - террористической организации, запрещенной в России.